# MikroTik: Set scan-list in RoS to ONLY use 2.4 GHz non-overlapping channel frequencies

Tags: wifi, mikrotik, routeros

How do I set the `scan-list` in MikroTik RouterOS to use only 2.4 GHz ***non-overlapping*** channel frequencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `scan-list` to **ONLY** use 2.4 GHz ***non-overlapping*** channel ***1,6 & 11*** in *MikroTik RouterOS* (*currently v6.46.5*):

```
/interface wireless set scan-list=2412,2437,2462 numbers=wlan1
```

Obviously change `wlan1` to the correct value as necessary for the radio you're working with in your MikroTik-